# Button has delayed response inside Page Control

Tags: ios, button, delay, uipageviewcontroller

I'm building an iOS application. I have some buttons inside a UIPageViewController, but all of them have a delayed response. They get highlighted only 1 second after I press them.

Basically, the buttons aren't responsive, how do I fix this?

Comment: Are they not responsive in emulator or on real device?

Comment: Both.. I think it's the Page Control